Equivalence between controllability criteria
I've occasionally found myself looking for a proof of the equivalence of some of the characterizations of controllability for input-state systems. Sometimes I've found a suitable proof, and sometimes I've given up and come up with the proof for myself.
The purpose of this post is to present my own proof of the following result:

Given matrices $A \in \Bbb C^{n \times n}, B \in \Bbb C^{n \times m}$, the following conditions are equivalent:

The discrete time system input-state system governed by $\mathbf x[k + 1] = A\mathbf x[k] + B\mathbf u[k]$ is controllable
The continuous time system input-state system governed by $\dot {\mathbf x}(t) = A\mathbf x(t) + B\mathbf u(t)$ is controllable
The controllability matrix
$$
\mathcal C(A,B) = [B\ \ AB \ \ \cdots\ \ A^{n-1}B]
$$
has full row-rank (i.e. has rank $n$)
The controllability Gramian
$$
W_c(t) = \int_0^t e^{A t}BB^*e^{A^* t}\,dt
$$
is invertible for any $t > 0$
(Hautus Lemma) The matrix $[\lambda I - A \ \ \ B]$ has full row rank for all $\lambda \in \Bbb C$.
The $A$-invariant subspace generated by the columns of $B$ is $\Bbb C^n$.


It will take me a while to put my answer together; any relevant comments or contributions are welcome in the meantime.

For reference, the definition controllability:
Discrete time: For any initial state $x_0$ and any final state $x_f$, there exists an input sequence $u:\Bbb N \to \Bbb C^m$ such that $x(k_0) = x_f$ for some positive integer $k$
Continuous time: For any initial state $x_0$ and any final state $x_f$, there exists an (integrable) input function $u:\Bbb [0,\infty) \to \Bbb C^m$ such that $x(t_0) = x_f$ for some $t_0 > 0$.

Aren't all the proofs of these in the literature or in textbooks? Theorem 6.1 and Theorem 6.D1 of C.-T. Chen's Linear System Theory and Design has (almost) all of them. Not sure (6) is in there..but i suspect that can be found in Wonham's text. I won't mine for that theorem now, so maybe i'm wrong about that one.

I’ve found bits in different textbooks, but in the end of the day I thought it would be good to provide a freely accessible consolidated version

The following results will be used.

Lemma 1: (Expression for discrete-time state trajectory) The discrete-time input-state system with initial state $\mathbf x[0]$ and input sequence $\mathbf u[k]$ has a state trajectory expressible as
$$
\mathbf x[k] = A^k\mathbf x[0] + \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} A^{j}B\mathbf u[k-j]
$$
Lemma 2: (Expression for continuous-time state trajectory) The discrete-time input-state system with initial state $\mathbf x(0)$ and input sequence $\mathbf u(t)$ has a state trajectory expressible as
$$
\mathbf x(t) = e^{At}\mathbf x(0) + \int_0^t e^{A(t - \tau)}B\mathbf u(\tau)\,d\tau
$$
Lemma 3: For an $n \times n$ continuous matrix-valued function $M(t)$, the Gramian matrix $\int_{t_0}^{t_f}M(t)M^*(t)\,dt$ is invertible if and only if for vectors $\mathbf q \in \Bbb C^n$, $\mathbf q^* M(t) \equiv 0$ over $[t_0,t_f]$ implies that $\mathbf q = \mathbf 0$.

To prove Lemma 3, it suffices to note that
$$
\int_{t_0}^{t_f}\|M^*(t)\mathbf q\|^2\,dt = \mathbf q^*\left[\int_{t_0}^{t_f}M(t)M^*(t)\,dt\right]\mathbf q,
$$
and that non-negative continuous functions over an interval are zero if and only if their integral is zero.

$1 \iff 3$:
This proof is given in the current Wikipedia article on controllability, I briefly paraphrase it here. By Lemma 1, we have
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbf x(n) - A^n\mathbf x(0) &= 
\begin{bmatrix}
B & AB & \cdots & A^{n-1} B
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf u^T(n-1) & \mathbf u^T(n-2) & \cdots & \mathbf u^T(0)
\end{bmatrix}^T
\\ & = \mathcal C(A,B)[\mathbf u(k)]_{k=0}^{n-1}
\end{align*}
$$
With that established, suppose that the discrete system is controllable. Then the above equation shows that every possible $\mathbf x(n) - A^n \mathbf x(0) \in \Bbb C^n$ arises as $\mathcal C(A,B) \mathbf v$ for some $\mathbf v \in \Bbb C^{mn}$, so that $\mathcal C(A,B)$ must have full row rank. Conversely, if $\mathcal C(A,B)$ has full row rank, then an inital state $\mathbf x_0$ may be steered towards $\mathbf x_f$ at time $k = n$ using an input sequence such that the vector $\mathbf v = [\mathbf u(k)]_{k=0}^{n-1}$ satisfies $\mathcal C(A,B)\mathbf v = \mathbf x(n) - A^n\mathbf x(0)$.
$2 \iff 3$:
(Argument adapted from Kailath's "Linear Systems"). Note: this argument requires the use of the impulse function (the Dirac-delta) and its derivative.
Given a continuous-time system with initial state $\mathbf x(0_-) = \mathbf x_0$ that is supplied with input
$$
\mathbf u(t) = \mathbf g_0\delta(t) + \cdots + \mathbf g_{n-1} \delta^{(n-1)}(t)
$$
the state of the system at the (infinitessimal) time $0_+$ is given by
$$
\mathbf x(0_+) = \mathbf x(0_-) + \mathcal C(A,B)
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf g_1^T & \mathbf g_2^T & \cdots & \mathbf g_{n-1}^T
\end{bmatrix}
$$
With that, any desired state can be reached by selecting vectors $\mathbf g_{k}$ such that $\mathbf v = [\mathbf g_k]_{k=0}^{n-1}$ satisfies $\mathcal C(A,B)\mathbf v = \mathbf x_f - \mathbf x_0$.
(From a practical standpoint, this can be used to show that the state $\mathbf x_f$ can be reached over arbitrarily small time-intervals, assuming that the system is controllable.)
Conversely, suppose that the system is controllable. Let $\mathbf q \in \Bbb C^n$ denote any vector such that $\mathbf q^* \mathcal C(A,B) = 0$. By controllability, there exists an input $\mathbf u(t)$ such that $\mathbf x(0) = \mathbf 0$ and $\mathbf (t_0) = \mathbf q$ for some $t_0 > 0$. It follows that
$$
\mathbf q = \int_0^{t_0} e^{A(t_0 - \tau)}B \mathbf u(\tau)\,d \tau.
$$
However, $\mathbf q^* \mathcal C(A,B) = 0$ implies that $\mathbf q^* A^kB = 0$ for all $k = 0,1,2,\dots$. Thus,
\begin{align*}
\mathbf q^*\mathbf q &= \mathbf q^*
\int_0^{t_0} e^{A(t_0 - \tau)}B \mathbf u(\tau)\,d \tau
\\ & = \int_0^{t_0} \mathbf q^*e^{A(t_0 - \tau)}B \mathbf u(\tau)\,d \tau
\\ & = 
\int_0^{t_0} \mathbf q^*\left[\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac 1{k!}(t_0 - \tau)^kA^k\right]B \mathbf u(\tau)\,d \tau
\\ & = 
\int_0^{t_0} \left[\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac 1{k!}(t_0 - \tau)^k \underbrace{\mathbf q^* A^k B}_0\right] \mathbf u(\tau)\,d \tau = 0
\end{align*}
That is, $\mathbf q^*\mathbf q = \|\mathbf q\|^2 = 0$. So, $\mathbf q = \mathbf 0$. So, the left-nullspace of $\mathcal C(A,B)$ is trivial. So, $\mathcal C(A,B)$ has full row-rank.
$3 \iff 6$:
It suffices to show that the $A$-invariant subspace generated by the columns of $B$ is equal to the column space of $\mathcal C(A,B)$.
The $A$-invariant subspace generated by the columns of $B$ is spanned by vectors the form $v = p(A)B\mathbf u$ for some polynomial $p$ and some vector $\mathbf u \in \Bbb C^m$. By the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, it suffices to consider polynomials of degree $n$. For a polynomial $p(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + \cdots + a_{n-1}x^{n-1}$, we have
$$
p(A)B\mathbf u = \mathcal C(A,B)\left(
\begin{bmatrix}
a_0 & a_1 & \cdots & a_{n-1}
\end{bmatrix}^T \otimes \mathbf u
\right),
$$
where $\otimes$ denotes a Kronecker product. Conclude that the column space of $\mathcal C(A,B)$ contains this $A$-invariant subspace. Conversely, each column of $\mathcal C(A,B)$ is of the form $A^kB\mathbf e_j$ for some standard basis vector $\mathbf e_j \in \Bbb C^m$, so the column space of $C(A,B)$ is contained within this $A$-invariant subspace.
$5 \iff 6$:
Suppose that $[\lambda I - A\quad B]$ fails to have full row-rank for some $\lambda \in \Bbb C$. Let $c \in \Bbb C^n$ denote a non-zero element of $\text{Nul}[\lambda I - A\quad B]^*$. We have
$$
c^*[\lambda I - A \quad B] = 0 \implies c^*(\lambda I - A) = 0 \text{ and } c^*B = 0.
$$
From the fact that $c^* (\lambda I - A) = 0$, we conclude that $c^* A = \lambda c^*$. Thus, for any polynomial $p$, we have
$$
c^*p(A)B\mathbf u = p(\lambda)c^*B \mathbf u = 0
$$
Thus, the invariant subspace spanned by the columns of $B$ lies within $c^\perp$, and so 5 is false.
Conversely, suppose that the $A$-invariant subspace generated by the columns of $B$ is a proper subspace of $\Bbb C^n$. Let $X$ denote its orthogonal complement. We note that $X$ is an $A^*$-invariant subspace. Indeed, for any polynomials $p,q$ and any $c \in X$, we have
$$
[q(A^*)c]^*p(A)B = c^*q(A)p(A)B = 0.
$$
It follows that $X$ contains an eigenvector of $A^*$. Let $x \in X$ be a non-zero vector such that $A^*x = \bar \lambda x$. It follows that
$$
x^*[A - \lambda I\quad B] = 0,
$$
so that the Hautus critereon fails to hold.
$2 \iff 4$
(Again, adapted from Kailath's "Linear Systems"). We make use of Lemma 3 to reframe condition 4 as stating that for vectors $\mathbf q \in \Bbb C^n$, $\mathbf q^* e^{At}B = 0$ can only hold over an interval $[0,t]$ if $\mathbf q = \mathbf 0$.
Suppose that the continuous-time system is controllable (condition 2). Let $\mathbf q$ be any non-zero vector in $\mathbf C^n$. There exists an input $\mathbf u(t)$ such that $\mathbf x(0) = \mathbf 0$ and $\mathbf (t_0) = \mathbf q$ for some $t_0 > 0$. It follows that
$$
\mathbf q = \int_0^{t_0} e^{A(t_0 - \tau)}B \mathbf u(\tau)\,d \tau.
$$
Thus,
$$
0 < \|\mathbf q\|^2 = \mathbf q^*\mathbf q = \int_0^{t_0} \mathbf q^*(e^{A(t_0 - \tau)}B) \mathbf u(\tau)\,d \tau.
$$
Thus, $\mathbf q^*(e^{A(t_0 - \tau)}B)$ cannot be uniformly zero over the interval.
Conversely, suppose that the Gramian is invertible. It suffices to confirm that any desired change in state $\mathbf x_0$ to $\mathbf x_f$ over the interval $[0,t_0]$ can be achieved via the input
$$
\mathbf u_*(\tau) = B^* e^{A^* (t_0 - \tau)} \left[\int_0^{t_0} e^{A\tau}BB^*e^{A^*\tau}\,d\tau\right]^{-1}(\mathbf x_f - e^{At_0}\mathbf x_0).
$$
Indeed,
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{t_0} e^{A(t - \tau)}\mathbf u_*(\tau)\,d\tau &= 
\int_0^{t_0} e^{A(t - \tau)}BB^* e^{A(t_0 - \tau)} \left[\int_0^{t_0} e^{A\tau}BB^*e^{A^*\tau}\,d\tau\right]^{-1}
(\mathbf x_f - e^{At_0}\mathbf x_0)
\,d\tau
\\ & = 
\left[\int_0^{t_0} e^{A(t - \tau)}BB^* e^{A(t_0 - \tau)} 
\,d\tau\right] \left[\int_0^{t_0} e^{A\tau}BB^*e^{A^*\tau}\,d\tau\right]^{-1}(\mathbf x_f - e^{At_0}\mathbf x_0)
\\ & = 
\left[\int_0^{t_0} e^{A\tau}BB^* e^{A\tau} 
\,d\tau\right] \left[\int_0^{t_0} e^{A\tau}BB^*e^{A^*\tau}\,d\tau\right]^{-1}(\mathbf x_f - e^{At_0}\mathbf x_0)
\\ & = \mathbf x_f - e^{At_0}\mathbf x_0,
\end{align*}
so that by Lemma 2 we have
$$
\mathbf x(t_0) = e^{At_0}\mathbf x_0 + 
\int_0^{t_0} e^{A(t - \tau)}\mathbf u_*(\tau)\,d\tau = 
e^{At_0} \mathbf x_0 + \mathbf x_f - e^{At_0}\mathbf x_0 = \mathbf x_f.
$$

The above proofs are sufficient, but I'm adding below any proofs that I find particularly interesting.
$4 \iff 6$:
As noted above, condition 4 can be reframed as stating that for vectors $\mathbf q \in \Bbb C^n$, $\mathbf q^* e^{At}B = 0$ can only hold over an interval $[0,t]$ if $\mathbf q = \mathbf 0$.
With that stated, we can show that $4 \iff 6$ by showing that the $A$-invariant subspace spanned by the columns of $B$ is equal to the column space of the Gramian, which is the smallest subspace containing $\text{Col}[e^{A\tau}B]$ for each $\tau \in [0,t]$.
Begin by showing that the smallest subspace containing each of these column spaces must be $A$-invariant (using derivatives, for instance) and contain the columns of $B$, showing one direction of inclusion. For the reverse inclusion, it suffices to note that $\text{Col}[e^{A\tau }B]$ lies within this invariant subspace as a consequence of the Cayley Hamilton theorem.
Interestingly, incorporating this eliminates the need to rely on dirac delta functions since the $2 \iff 3$ proof becomes unnecessary.
$(3\text{ or }6) \implies 2$:
Can also be shown by considering the zero-order hold discretization of the continuous time system and showing that the resulting discrete system has a controllability matrix with the same column space
